# Azure Data Factory V2 - publish pipeline to specified folder

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, azure-data-factory

While developing in Azure Portal, I can organize pipelines, datasets and linked services in folders. JSON file of pipeline will contain folder name:

```
"folder": {
  "name": "Business"
}
```

But when I publish pipeline (or any other DF V2 object) with PowerShell Cmd-Let, it goes to the root folder:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryV2Name -File $filePath `
  -Name $name -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

Is there a way to force Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline and related Cmd-Lets to honor "folder" path and publish object to the specified folder?

Comment: I think you are asking some kind of container which can help you group particular ADF objects. This is currently not supported. But I think you can create multiple data factories to achieve that purpose.

Comment: The feature I'm asking about already works, our developers happily use it. But it works only when publishing DF V2 objects from Azure Portal UI. When we use powershell scripts (for deployment automation) it moves all the objects to the root folder, which irritates devs as they have to manually reorganize objects by folders after such automated deployment.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Please update once you get solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Microsoft fixed the issue and in version 6.10.0 Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Pipeline properly puts pipeline into the specified folder!

Answer (score -1):

Powershell doesn't support it because it ignores properties it can't recognize. And currently, this property is also not supported by SDK.

But you could Restful API to achieve this. And if you have to use powershell, you could use the [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6).