# Publish ADF files to specific folder within project

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can I have all files generated by the publishing within a specific folder on an Azure DevOps repo?

I've tried to specify the relative path on the **Root folder** property on the Git repository configuration as follows:

---

[image]

---

#### But it keeps duplicating the files at the root of the project

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with some more information on what you're trying to achieve, what you have tried and what didn't work. This helps us help you. For more information, see [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Data Factory V2 - publish pipeline to specified folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158909/azure-data-factory-v2-publish-pipeline-to-specified-folder)

Comment: @rickvdbosch it doesn't answer my question as my issue is not related to PowerShell nor I am configuring things through JSON. Thanks for sharing tho. Anyhoo, just added further information to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a misconfiguration on my end. Indeed the proper way to deploy ADF metadata within a specific folder is declaring the relative path on the **Root folder** property.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever we hit the publish button from main branch in adf, adf_publish branch is generated where you actually publish your production ready code from your collaboration branch ( main or master branch) to Data factory service. This branch contains the ARM templates of those artifacts that you have published to Data factory service from your collaboration branch in the form of these .json files:

1. ARMTemplateForFactory.json – This is the ARM template file that consists of ALL the resources that you have in the ADF pipeline.
2. ARMTemplateParameterForFactory.json – The parameters that the ARM Template would need. The parameter files contains all the names and configurations of the services that are environment specific.

This is the default behavior when we publish our changes in ADF. As it is auto-generated branch, it's not editable.